# Writing a reverse iterator python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm trying to write my own reverse iterator wothout using reverse-funtion.
My question is how do it?
This code is not working.

```
def my_iter(iterable):
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(iterable) - 1, -1, -1):
        #print(i)
        j = 0
        temp[i] = iterable[i]
        j += 1
    return temp
```

For example:
my_list = [78, 120, 3]
my_iter(my_list)
output : 3, 120, 78

Comment: Format your question : there is no question mark in it ??
This probably won't work because ``temp`` is empty. You need to add something to it.
Also, try and use ``iterable[::-1]`` if you wish to hack it

Comment: Terminology nitpick: you are not writing an iterator at all. You are *iterating* in reverse order, but you haven't written a reverse iterator.

Comment: @BornTbeWasted where should I use ```iterable[::-1]```?

Comment: @Elgernon that is literally all you need to reverse a list (any sequence that supports slicing, really, like a `str` or a `tuple`). So `my_list_reversed = my_list[::-1]`, of course, if you aren't supposed to use `reversed`, then you probably aren't meant to use `[::-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a two pointer approach to reverse the list.

```
def my_iter(iterable):
    i = 0
    j = len(iterable)-1
    while i <= j:
        temp = iterable[i]
        iterable[i] = iterable[j]
        iterable[j] = temp
        i+=1
        j-=1
    return iterable

print(my_iter([78, 120, 3]))
#[3, 120, 78]
```

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @Elgernon note, *this does not use an iterator*

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a custom reverse iterator when you can directly iterate over `iterable[::-1]`. With `yield` in loop, you can harvest the advantages of generator:

```
def my_iter(iterable):
    for x in iterable[::-1]:
        yield x

my_list = [78, 120, 3]

rev_iter = my_iter(my_list)

print(next(rev_iter))  # 3
print(next(rev_iter))  # 120
print(next(rev_iter))  # 78

# calling next() again throws a StopIteration.
```

Comment: I need to do it exactly through the iterator.

Comment: What, exactly, is the advantage of wrapping it up in generator here?

Comment: @Elgernon note, *this does use an iterator*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I know how it is used. Generator is my next task. Thank you.